# keeps printing one page

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

i want to print all the items in my listbox and if there are more items I want them to be continued on the next page. To do this, every time an item is written the `pageRecordIndex` increases by 1 and if the `pageRecordIndex` doesn't equate to the number of items in the listbox then `e.HasMorePages` is set to `True` but once the first page is full the rest of the items don't print on the next page.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim pageRecordIndex = 0
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim mem As String
    Dim yOffset As Integer = 10

    If pageRecordIndex < ListBox1.Items.Count Then
        For index = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            mem = ListBox1.Items(index)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(mem,
                              Me.Font,
                              Brushes.Black,
                              10,
                              yOffset)

            pageRecordIndex = pageRecordIndex + 1
            yOffset += 20
        Next
        If pageRecordIndex = ListBox1.Items.Count Then
            e.HasMorePages = False
            Exit Sub
        Else
            e.HasMorePages = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

i tried setting the `e.hasmorepages` outside the first `If` statement but still no luck. Did a `Do While` loop as well and that didn't work. Is the way I'm keeping track of my records by having `pageRecordIndex` not right? What is the issue here?

Before marking as a duplicate leave a comment saying how i can implement other solution onto mine because I've seen similar posts and the solutions did not work for me.

Comment: How is this different than your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45787197/1070452) which itself is a dupe?

Comment: you marked it as a duplicate but the solutions of the other posts did not work @Plutonix

Comment: This post has the same problem as the last one - your For/Loop starts at zero for each page.  The problem is amply covered in both the posts linked in your original post.  its not about `e.HasMorePages` its about the index.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: so i tried setting the index = pageRecordIndex but it's doing the same thing. can you not provide an example

Comment: Can you not *study* the already crafted examples and focus on the loop indexer?  Your code above is a pale and flawed translation of one of the dupes. The answers ***both*** rely on a variable declared ***outside*** the print method which keeps track of where the last page left off.

Comment: The trick to using the `HasMorePages` property is to set it to `true` and then _exit the print handler immediately_.  The `Print_Page` handler will then be called again automatically.  You have to keep track of what you have already printed _outside_ the print page handler.  When the print page handler is called again, you have to continue from where the last call of the handler left off.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

For index = pageRecordIndex To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

Comment: i've tried that but didn't work. Also tried deleting the If statements and at the end entered `e.hasmorepages = pageRecordIndex > Listbox1.items.count` but no luck

Comment: Now I unterstand! You have to count Outside. Look to the first Link above.

Comment: @nikolas yea i looked at the first link mutiple times but don't understand. care to explain plz?

Comment: Your event can only Print 1 Page and because you initialise your pageRecordIndex in the Method it always starts from new. Try to Use all the Code, which is provided in the Post, then u should get a working Solution.